# ¿Como contar las veces que se repite una letra en una palabra?

Tags: c

El ejercicio consiste en lo siguiente

> Escriba un programa que lea una palabra desde teclado y luego informe la cantidad de veces que
> aparece cada letra de la palabra leída en ella misma.
> Nota: asuma que la palabra está formada sólo por letras minúsculas.

No se me ocurre otra forma que crear 3 arreglos. Uno para cada letra del abecedario, uno como contador y otro donde guardar la palabra leída. Al comienzo había pensando en una matriz de 26 filas y 2 columnas, pero me encontré con la dificultad de guardar elementos de dos tipos diferentes.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora de mi función contar:

```c
void Contar(char letras[], char palabra[], int contador[])
{
    int i,j,longitud=strlen(palabra);
    for(i=0;i<longitud;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        while(palabra[i]!=letras[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        contador[j]++;
    }
}
```

Por si no se entiende, lo que hace es recorrer [letras] hasta encontrar en dicho vector, la posición donde está la primera letra del vector [palabra] y asi sucesivamente. Esto lo repite evidentemente, "longitud" veces. Pero cuanto mas larga sea la palabra leída, mas veces recorre el vector.

**Mi pregunta es si se les ocurre otra forma de resolverlo recorriendo la menor cantidad de veces posible y esto sin usar funciones dadas por el lenguaje. Ya que usamos muy pocas de estas.**

Comment: La palabra puede tener eñes?

Comment: La forma mas eficiente y eficaz para resolver este problema es usando un table hash. No existe funciones en la biblioteca estandar de C que permitan crear tables hash, asi que te tocaria crearla manualmente o usar alguna biblioteca de terceros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente no necesitas un array con las letras del abecedario. Si miras cualquier tabla ASCII verás que cualquier caracter es convertible a un entero de 8 bits ... que es el tipo que usa la máquina realmente.

Así, puedes hacer un bucle que itere desde el valor de `'a'` hasta el valor de `'z'`

```
void Contar(char const* palabra, int * contador)
{
  int longitud = strlen(palabra);
  for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++)
  {
    for( char letra = 'a'; letra <= 'z'; ++letra )
    {
      if( letra == palabra[i] )
      {
        contador[letra - 'a']++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Aquí vemos cómo podemos tratar los caracteres como si de números se tratasen ... detallitos del lenguaje. Pues bien, si seguimos dándole vueltas podemos ver que realmente no hace falta saber qué letra tenemos en cada iteración ... basta con coger la letra y actualizar el contador que corresponda:

```
void Contar(char const* palabra, int * contador)
{
  int longitud = strlen(palabra);
  for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++)
  {
    char letra = palabra[i];
    contador[letra - 'a']++;
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, has comentado que no hay que usar funciones dadas por el lenguaje... ¿por qué usamos entonces `strlen`?

```
void Contar(char const* palabra, int * contador)
{
  for(char const* ptr = palabra; *ptr; ++ptr )
  {
    char letra = *ptr;
    contador[letra - 'a']++;
  }
}
```

El bucle es muy sencillo de entender:

- Inicialmente, `ptr` apunta al inicio de la palabra (al primer caracter)
- La condición es que el caracter apuntado por `ptr` no sea el caracter nulo (ese caracter casualmente vale 0, por lo que se evalua como `false`, mientras que cualquier otro valor se evaluará como `true`)
- En cada iteración incrementamos `ptr` para que apunte al siguiente caracter

Pues bien, incluso con esta función con 4 líneas mal puestas puede presentarse de forma un poco poco más compacta con un esfuerzo mínimo:

```
void Contar(char const* palabra, int * contador)
{
  for(char const* ptr = palabra; *ptr; ++ptr )
  {
    contador[*ptr-'a']++;
  }
}
```

Incluso, ya puestos podríamos seguir compactando aun más el código, claro que entonces cuesta algo más entenderlo

```
void Contar(char const* ptr, int * contador)
{
    for(; *ptr && ++contador[*ptr - 'a']; ++ptr );
}
```

Aquí abusamos un poco de una características del lenguaje:

El operador `&&` evalúa inicialmente el término de la izquierda y, solo si este término es verdadero, se evalúa el término de la derecha. Es decir, primero se verifica si hemos llegado al final de la cadena y, mientras esto no se cumpla, se evalúa (ejecuta) la parte de la derecha.

Answer (score 2):

Tenemos una función `Contar` que recibe la palabra como un arreglo de caracteres. La función recorre esa palabra letra por letra en un ciclo `for`.

Truco 1: Declaro un arreglo de contadores dentro de la función con el atributo `static`. El arreglo entonces es permanente; no desaparece al terminar la función. Así puedo devolver un puntero, lo que permite al llamante acceder a los contadores. También tengo que inicializar los contadores en cada llamada:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 26; i++) {
    contador[i] = 0;
}
```

Truco 2: Puedes convertir un caracter en su número de secuencia simplemente restando el primer caracteres del alfabeto:

```
int letra = palabra[i] - 'a';
```

Lo que transforma 'a' -> 0, 'b' -> 1, etc. Eso lo puedo usar para indexar un arreglo de contadores.

De ahi sólo me queda recorrer y contar:

```
int* Contar(char palabra[]){
    static int contador[26];
    for (int i= 0; i < 26; i++) {
        contador[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=0; palabra[i]; i++) {
        int letra = palabra[i] - 'a';
        contador[letra]++;
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Con esta función pruebo:

```
int main() {
    int* contador = Contar("supermegafantistiquin");
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        char letra = 'a' + i;
        int cta = *(contador + i);
        if (cta) {
            printf("Letra %c aparece %d veces\n", letra, cta);
        }       
    }
}
```

produce:

```
Letra a aparece 2 veces
Letra e aparece 2 veces
Letra f aparece 1 veces
Letra g aparece 1 veces
Letra i aparece 3 veces
Letra m aparece 1 veces
Letra n aparece 2 veces
Letra p aparece 1 veces
Letra q aparece 1 veces
Letra r aparece 1 veces
Letra s aparece 2 veces
Letra t aparece 2 veces
Letra u aparece 2 veces
```